# location.hash issue in js

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have a piece of javascript that I inherited; it's being used as a tab switcher. Unfortunately it's not working. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* This is the back button friendly tab switcher */
    var trackContainers = $('.switcher > .results');
  trackContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

  $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash || '#dpp';
    console.log('hash: ' + hash);

    trackContainers.hide();
    trackContainers.filter(hash).show();
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $('a[hash='+hash+']').parent().addClass('active');
  });

  $(window).trigger("hashchange").location(hash);

});
```

What's supposed to happen is when a specific tab is clicked, it changes the class of the li tag surrounding the clicked tab. Here's what the tab code looks like:

```
<div class="switcher"> 
<ul class="tabs"> 
<li  class="inactive"><a href="#dpp">Digital Path to Purchase</a></li> 
<li class="inactive"><a href="#cre">Fueling Creativity</a></li> 
<li class="inactive"><a href="#bpp">Best Practices/Big Picture</a></li> 
<li class="inactive"><a href="#si">Shopper Insights 101</a></li> 
<li class="inactive"><a href="#dem">Who Is Your Shopper</a></li> 
<li class="inactive"><a href="#gt">Google Theater</a></li> 
<li class="inactive"><a href="#res">Understanding the Shopper</a></li> 
<li class="inactive"><a href="#bar">Brand Activation at Retail</a></li> 
<li class="active"><a href="#duc">Deeper Understanding of Center Store</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div> 
</div>
```

You can see that the link called #duc has the active class on its li item. However, when I look at the script code in Firebug, it gives me an error saying hash is not defined:

[image]

Again, looking in Firebug, but this time at the console tab, it very clearly shows that hash IS defined:

[image]

Can anyone point out how it's losing its definition between the console.log and the .trigger lines?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you are defining hash within the scope of your bind function :

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash || '#dpp';
```

It therefore does not exist outside of that function. 
If you wanted access to that variable based off the value the window.location.hash was at the time of your hashchange event, I would create a variable outside of the bind 'hashchange' function so it has access to that variable.

```
var hash;

$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    hash = window.location.hash || '#dpp';
    console.log('hash: ' + hash);

     trackContainers.hide();
     trackContainers.filter(hash).show();
     $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
     $('a[hash='+hash+']').parent().addClass('active');
});
$(window).trigger("hashchange").location(hash);
```

But the value of hash at the $(window).trigger("hashchange") line will not be set more than likely because that event may not have fired and the

```
hash = window.location.hash || '#dpp';
```

line will not have been run. I think you need to examine the workflow a little closer.

Comment: You're right - the event doesn't seem to be firing. Why not, though? The hash IS changing in the URL when I click the various tabs.

Comment: This works for me (typing in the console in stackoverflow will work) : `$(window).bind('hashchange',function(){console.log("CHANGIFIED");}); ` followed by : `$(window).trigger("hashchange");`

Comment: I noticed that `$(window).location` isn't valid (jQuery doesn't pass back the original 'window' object)... so to trigger you might try `window.location = "#dpp"`  instead of `$(window).trigger("hashchange").location(hash);` to initially trigger your workflow.

Comment: Thanks. Still didn't work. This is code I inherited, and I have no indication that it ever worked, so I think I'm going to start over using a different method.

Comment: Sorry, hash changes can be tricky. I also understand that you won't get a hashchange event firing unless the actual url changes. So if your url is already   http://myurl.com#dpp  then if you try and trigger a hashchange event with window.location = "#dpp" it won't work. You would need to start the workflow manually using `$(window).trigger('hashchange');`  Good luck! Also take a look at the jQuery bbq plugin. It is great at handling hash changes in a predictable way.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the URL won't change when clicking the various tabs, except for the hash values.

Comment: where exactly would I start the workflow manually? It can't be inside the bind function.

Comment: Yeah that's fine... the whole URL need not change, just the hash so that's good. Right, start things up outside of the bind function.  Picture it like setting up all the pins (the bind function) and the rolling your code bowling ball (after the bind function) `$(window).trigger('hashchange');`

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this. It's still not working, so there has to be some other script somewhere on the page interfering with it.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the `hash` variable is only the anonymous function being called in the `.bind()` section of the code, so doesn't exist once that function has finished executing.

Comment: Thanks. I moved the hash variable outside the bind function, but the tabs still don't switch. Obviously there's something else going on here.

Answer (score 1):

you want

```
$(window).trigger("hashchange").location(window.location.hash);
```

As Anthony Grist said, the variable hash you defined in the anonymous function doesn't exist by the time you get there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/*I moved it out of the function because the var was only in existence in the bind function before. Now its going to exist still when you call it at $(window)*/
var hash = window.location.hash || '#dpp';   


 /* This is the back button friendly tab switcher */
    var trackContainers = $('.switcher > .results');
  trackContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

  $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {

    //here, i'm simply changing its value, which was set on line 4 outside of the fn.
    hash = window.location.hash || '#dpp';
    console.log('hash: ' + hash);

    trackContainers.hide();
    trackContainers.filter(hash).show();
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $('a[hash='+hash+']').parent().addClass('active');
  });

  $(window).trigger("hashchange").location(hash);

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried, but gives me a different error now: `  $(window).trigger("hashchange").location(hash) is not a function`.